# How do I show Placeholder Backgrounds in Xcode Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode7

How do I set and show custom Placeholder Backgrounds in Xcode 7's Interface Builder?

This functionality was [added in Xcode 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW326), but I can't the way to set it.

> Background placeholders on custom views and other containers can be hidden on the Interface Builder canvas by selecting Editor > Canvas > Show Background Placeholders. (20580948)

I've enabled in but nothing changed and I can't find where I can set a custom placeholder image:

[image: Xcode's Editor menu's Canvas submenu expanded, with "Show Placeholder Backgrounds" checked]

Answer (score 1):

A few years later and Xcode 10 still *doesn't* provide any of the flexibility you had in mind back then

From Xcode 10 documentation:

> Use placeholder backgrounds to identify image views, MapKit views, MetalKit views, GLKit views, and SceneKit views. Hide the placeholder backgrounds to focus on the content of your own views.

[image]

> Choose Editor > Canvas > Show Placeholder Backgrounds to toggle showing placeholder backgrounds for *certain types* of views on the Interface Builder canvas.

The feature really is limited to *only* some of the built-in views from Apple (and even those that blue-ish background color is still pretty much hardcoded).